# How to install FlashBuilder 4.6 Eclipse plug-in on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, adobe, flash-builder

**Problem**

A few of us running either Mac OS X Snow Leopard or Lion and installing the FlashBuilder 4.6 eclipse plug-in are experiencing an issue where the plug-in simply does not show up in Eclipse. The installation adds a file under the /dropins directory called **fb-4_6-plugin-encoded.link** that is supposed to tell Eclipse the location of the Adobe FlashBuilder installation.

The scenarios we have encountered are as follows:

- Plug-in is registered, but does not show up.  Running Eclipse with `-consoleLog` shows no errors.
- Eclipse running with the -consoleLog switch says that the **fb-4_6-plugin-encoded.link** file is not accessible.  Doing a `chmod 777` on the file fixes the issue and the plug-in is registered.

Here are the notes from the **README** that comes with FlashBuilder:

---

> Flash Builder 4.6 supports installation as a plugin to an existing
>   Eclipse instance.
>
> To do so:
>
> 1. Complete the installation process as described above.
> 2. Navigate to the installed Flash Builder installation location and open the utilities folder.
> 3. Run the executable Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 Plug-in Utility.app.
> 4. Select the language and click on OK.
> 5. Select the Flash Builder installation location if prompted.
> 6. Select the eclipse folder into which you want Flash Builder 4.6 to be plugged into and click Next. (Note: Your copy of Eclipse must be
>      version 3.6/3.6.1/3.6.2/3.7, 32-bit, Cocoa, containing a folder named
>      “dropins”).
> 7. Review the pre-Installation summary and click on Install.
> 8. Following installation it is recommended that you edit the eclipse.ini file for your Eclipse instance, so that it includes the
>      following settings:
>      -vmargs -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=64m

---

**Questions**

Is there any Eclipse magic that can be performed to further investigate the issue? Is there any way to manually register the FlashBuilder plug-in (or generally a dropins style plug-in)?

Comment: Maybe you should contact Adobe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same problem.

I executed.

```
/Applications/eclipse/eclipse -consoleLog
```

Error happened like this:

> 1 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/eclipse/dropins/fb-4_6-plugin-encoded.link (Permission denied)
>   2 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>   3 at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>   4 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.getLinkedRep ository(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:133)

To solve problem, I did two command:

```
chown YOUR_LOGIN_ACCOUNT fb-4_6-plugin-encoded.link  
chmod 755 fb-4_6-plugin-encoded.link
```

The plugin showed up.